# Strange display using java.util.Properties

Tags: java, properties, iterator, fileinputstream

I have a .properties file, who has this format :

```
toto=titi
fofo=fifi
coco=cici
mama=momo
dada=didi
```

I'm having a strange display when I parse this file. This is the code I'm using :

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
String fileLocation = "C:/myProperties.properties";
prop.load(new FileInputStream(fileLocation));

Iterator<Object> it = prop.keySet().iterator();
int line = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) 
{
       String propertyName = (String) it.next(); 
       if (propertyName.equals("coco"))
       {
          System.out.println("coco found at line : " + line);
          break;
       }

       else if (propertyName.equals("titi"))
       {
          System.out.println("Titi found at line : " + line);
          break;
       }

       line++;
}
```

What do you think I will have in output ?

I will edit the question after your answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Properties` object is backed by a `Map` implementation so don't rely on the ordering of your properties. If you have something else to report as "strange" please elaborate your question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Line number is not relevant as `Properties` uses hash to store elements. Order is not preserved.